# Необходимо кешировать данные с помощью memcached

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached

Пробовал гетеры сетеры, но ничего не выводится, даже прологировать не вышло(попали ли данные в кеш или нет или подключился memcached или нет) https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached

---

Пробовал вот такой вариант, но опять же ничего не выводится
https://jsonworld.com/demo/how-to-implement-memcached-in-nodejs-application

```js
var Memcached = require('memcached');
// Created object for memcached
var memcached = new Memcached();
/* code to connect with your memecahced server */
memcached.connect( 'localhost:11211', function( err, conn ){//Если прописать localhost:3000, то в console.log(conn); выводится следующее, если же использовать localhost:11211, то ничего не выводится...
  /*      vnodes: {},
        servers: [],
        cache: [Cache] },
     connections:
      { 'localhost:3000': [Manager], 'localhost:11211': [Manager] },
     issues: [] },
  [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11,
  [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
  [Symbol(timeout)]:
   Timeout {
     _called: false,
     _idleTimeout: 5000,
     _idlePrev: [TimersList],
     _idleNext: [Timeout],
     _idleStart: 1820,
     _onTimeout: [Function: bound ],
     _timerArgs: undefined,
     _repeat: null,
     _destroyed: false,
     [Symbol(unrefed)]: true,
     [Symbol(asyncId)]: 164,
     [Symbol(triggerId)]: 24 },
  [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0 }*/
if( err ) {
  console.log( conn.server,'error while memcached connection!!');
}
});

var user = {
  'userId':'iuytredcvb12345sdfgh',
  'userName':'testUser',
  'emailId':'demo.jsonworld@gmail.com',
  'phone' : 8287374553,
  'availableFor' : '2 hours',
  'createdOn':1543122402
}

memcached.set('user', user, 10000, function (err) {
  if(err) throw new err;
});

memcached.get('user', function (err, data) {
  //логировал попадание в функцию get, но функция не выполняется
  console.log(data);
});
```

Итоговая цель кешировать данные получаемые из бд

```js
router.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
  const dbItem = await Url.findOne({shortUrl: req.params.shortUrl});
  dbItem.counter = parseInt(++dbItem.counter);
  res.redirect(dbItem.url);
  dbItem.save();
});
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь